# missing 1 required positional argument: 'out' (Tkinter start and stop screen recording with buttons and class functions not working)

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to create a simple UI for `screenrecording`. In my UI i have two buttons "Start Screen Recording" and "Stop Screen Recording". I can start the screen recording but when i click the stop button the recording is not stopped and i'm getting the following output:

> Screenrecorder.stop_recording() missing 1 required positional argument: 'out'

This is my class Screenrecorder:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui

class Screenrecorder():

    def start_recording():
        # display screen resolution, get it using pyautogui itself
        SCREEN_SIZE = tuple(pyautogui.size())

        # define the codec
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")

        # frames per second
        fps = 12.0

        # create the video write object
        out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, fps, (SCREEN_SIZE))

        status = True
        while status:
            # make a screenshot
            img = pyautogui.screenshot()
            # convert these pixels to a proper numpy array to work with OpenCV
            frame = np.array(img)
            # convert colors from BGR to RGB
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            # write the frame
            out.write(frame)

            return out


    def stop_recording(out):
        # make sure everything is closed when exitedq
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        out.release()
```

Shouldn't my function "stop_recording" receive the "return out"? What am i doing wrong here?
I've read that using return is one solution to pass variables to other functions and i dont want to use global variables.

The UI code:

```
# ScreenRecorder
# from PyscreenrecClass import MyScreenRecorder
from CV2Class import ScreenRecorder
# import pyscreenrec
# Screenshot
from ScreenshotClass import Screenshot

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

root.title("Recorder")

root.geometry("400x900")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root) 
  
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 

tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Screen Recording') 
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Settings') 
tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both") 

sr = ScreenRecorder() # Right place?

Button(tab1, text="Activate Screenshot Mode", command=Screenshot.TakeScreenshot).pack()

Button(tab1, text="Start Screen Recording", command=sr.start_recording()).pack()

Button(tab1, text="Stop Screen Recording", command=sr.stop_recording()).pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `out` is not automatically passed to the `stop_recoding` function. You could expand your OOP approach by defining an `__init__` function for your class. There you could handle `out` as an instance variable which will it make accessible from other functions inside the class.

Comment: What is the parameter `out` for  `stop_recording(out)`?

Comment: Out is the cv2.VideoWriter and i thought i have to give stop_recording() out as an input value -> stop_recording(out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already tried an OOP approach, I have taken the liberty of improving it a little so that you do not have to pass `out`, but this is an instance variable (and thus accessible via `self`):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui


class ScreenRecorder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.out = None  # initialize out as instance variable

    def start_recording(self):
        # display screen resolution, get it using pyautogui itself
        SCREEN_SIZE = tuple(pyautogui.size())

        # define the codec
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")

        # frames per second
        fps = 12.0

        # assign the video write object to the instance variable
        self.out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, fps, (SCREEN_SIZE))

        status = True
        while status:
            # make a screenshot
            img = pyautogui.screenshot()
            # convert these pixels to a proper numpy array to work with OpenCV
            frame = np.array(img)
            # convert colors from BGR to RGB
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            # write the frame
            self.out.write(frame)

    def stop_recording(self):
        # make sure everything is closed when exited
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        self.out.release()  # access instance variable
        self.out = None  # reset instance variable to None
```

**PS:**

A `retrun` value is returned when the function is called, but must then also be "caught" (`out = Screenrecorder.start_recording()`). Without such an assignment, the `return` value is not used in another function. It would be possible, for example:  `Screenrecorder.stop_recording(Screenrecorder.start_recording())` to pass `out` directly to `stop_recording`. However, this obviously makes no sense as a button function, especially because then `out` is not the same object as the retrun value from pressing the start button. Rather, the first recording would continue to run and a new recording would be started and stopped immediately when stop is pressed.

---

**EDIT**

I changed the ode a little bit to work with tkinter as GUI. It is important to notice, that the tkinter `mainloop()` must be in the main thread and the GUI wont be responding if you call a funtion with a endless loop itself (`while True` in your recording function). Instead I outsourced the recording loop to a simple thread:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, Button
from _thread import start_new_thread


class ScreenRecorder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.out = None  # initialize out as instance variable
        self.status = False

    def start_recording(self):
        # display screen resolution, get it using pyautogui itself
        SCREEN_SIZE = tuple(pyautogui.size())
        # define the codec
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
        # frames per second
        fps = 12.0
        # assign the video write object to the instance variable
        self.out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, fps, (SCREEN_SIZE))
        # set status to True
        self.status = True
        # start record loop in new thread
        start_new_thread(self._record_loop, tuple())

    def _record_loop(self):
        while self.status:
            # make a screenshot
            img = pyautogui.screenshot()
            # convert these pixels to a proper numpy array to work with OpenCV
            frame = np.array(img)
            # convert colors from BGR to RGB
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            # write the frame if out still exists
            if self.out is not None:
                self.out.write(frame)

    def stop_recording(self):
        if self.status:  # make it only stop if a recording is going on
            # set status to False again
            self.status = False
            # make sure everything is closed when exited
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            self.out.release()  # access instance variable
            self.out = None  # reset instance variable to None


class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Recorder")
        self.geometry("400x900")
        mainframe = ttk.Frame(self)
        #self.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
        tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self)
        tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
        tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
        tabControl.add(tab1, text='Screen Recording')
        tabControl.add(tab2, text='Settings')
        tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
        sr = ScreenRecorder()
        #Button(tab1, text="Activate Screenshot Mode", command=Screenshot.TakeScreenshot).pack()
        Button(tab1, text="Start Screen Recording", command=sr.start_recording).pack()
        Button(tab1, text="Stop Screen Recording", command=sr.stop_recording).pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ui = GUI()
    ui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Jan! I've tried something like you did but its not working. I receive "ScreenRecorder.start_recording() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' ". I'm importing the class could this be the problem?

Comment: That is most likely due to not instanciating the class `ScreenRecorder` first. In your GUI code instanciate the class like so: `sr = ScreenRecorder()`. Then use `sr.start_recording()`

Comment: When i instanciate the class the UI opens but is not responding. Also the buttons are not visible. Can i write sr = ScreenRcorder() directly after the import of libraries and before my UI code? Like this `sr = ScreenRecorder()

root = Tk()

root.title("Recorder")

root.geometry("400x900")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
root.iconbitmap("icon.ico") ..... `

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your UI code... Could you update your question to include a full [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Or alternatively create a new question, since this seems like a new topic

Comment: I have attached the UI code to my question.

Comment: there are two problems: first - you call the function when assigning it to the button. Try removing the parantheses `Button(tab1, text="Start Screen Recording", command=sr.start_recording).pack()`. secondly - the screen recording (the `while status` loop) blocks the mainloop which causes your app to freeze... try to use threadding for the recording

Comment: Maby instead of using `_thread` you could look a little into `threadding` and especially how locks work, since you are working with `out` from two threads. Nontheless my edit should work, since i test if `out` still exists. As a sidenote: Maby disable the start and stop button respectively if a recording is beeing conducted or not or display a status label for the user to see what is happening.